# Numpy ndenumerate is incredibly slow. Is there a quicker way of using conditions on arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I have 26 arrays of data, I am working with incredibly large arrays so I would like to speed this process up. This code actually works and achieves what I want it to achieve but it is incredibly slow.

What I want the code to do is:

Look at two arrays and select cells for which a certain conditions are met or not met. If that condition is met then I would like to change the values in those cells by editing and taking values from another array. All the values in the arrays need to be updated to reflect those changes.

My code below may seem a little confusing but here goes. This is my slow code:

```
active_layer # An array

active_layer_volumes = [] # List of 7 arrays
active_layer_proportions = [] # List of 7 arrays

inactive_layer # Array

inactive_layer_volumes = [] # List of 7 arrays
inactive_layer_proportions = [] # List of 7 arrays

# Calculate the lower and upper limits for the volume of the active layer
al_upper_volume_limit = 5
al_lower_volume_limit = 1

# Count the grainsizes as the model works through them
grain_size_counter = 1    

# Set up some empty arrays to hold the new values 
new_active_layer_total = np.zeros_like(active_layer)
new_inactive_layer_total = np.zeros_like(inactive_layer)

# Iterate through the 24 arrays in order
for active_layer_proportion, active_layer_volume, inactive_layer_proportion, inactive_layer_volume in izip(active_layer_volumes, active_layer_proportions,inactive_layer_volumes, inactive_layer_proportions):

    # Iterate through all of the cells in the active layer checking to see if certain conditions are met 
    for [i, j], depth in np.ndenumerate(active_layer): # Iterate through the cells 

        if active_layer[i, j] >= al_upper_volume_limit: # check to see if the volume in that cell is greater than 5m3
           inactive_layer_volume[i, j] = (20 * active_layer_proportion[i, j]) + inactive_layer_volume[i, j] # add 20cm proportion of that grainsize to the active layer
           active_layer_volume[i, j] = (active_layer[i, j] - 20) * active_layer_proportion[i, j] 

        elif active_layer[i, j] < al_lower_volume_limit and inactive_layer[i, j] > 0: # check to see if the volume in that cell is greater than 5m3        
            active_layer_volume[i, j] = (20 * inactive_layer_proportion[i, j]) + active_layer_volume[i, j]                      
            inactive_layer_volume[i, j] = inactive_layer_volume[i, j] - (20 * inactive_layer_proportion[i, j])

    # Increment a counter as the loop goes through the arrays                      
    grain_size_counter + 1

    # Add the new calculated volumes to a running total array
    new_active_layer_total += active_layer_volume
    new_inactive_layer_total += inactive_layer_volume
```

Comment: Sounds like you want the `np.where` function ...

Comment: I think [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) could perhaps do what you want. You can create masks based on your conditionals, and then operate on the reminder.

Comment: Thanks will I am just looking at masked arrays now. Once I have used the masked array can I overwrite the values in the original array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the inner loop on `ndenumerate` with the following vectorized expressions:

```
# Array B contains True/False for the condition and is subsequently 
# used as Boolean index.
B = (active_layer >= al_upper_volume_limit)
inactive_layer_volume[B] += 20 * active_layer_proportion[B]
active_layer_volume[B] = (active_layer[B] - 20) * active_layer_proportion[B]

# The "not B" does the "else" part of the elif statement it replaces
B = ~B & (active_layer < al_lower_volume_limit) & (inactive_layer > 0)
active_layer_volume[B] += 20 * inactive_layer_proportion[B]                      
inactive_layer_volume[B] -= 20 * inactive_layer_proportion[B]
```